# React - Pass function to component that has default props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that uses default props:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log('props', props);
    super(props);

// rest of code here

}

MyComponent .defaultProps = {
  __TYPE: 'MyDateRange',
};
```

When I use the component, without passing any props, the console log of `props` shows the default props, like it should.

Now, when I want to pass an additional prop (a function in this case), like this:

```
<MyComponent onEnterKey={() => console.log('snuh')}/>
```

The console log of `props` only shows the `onEnterKey` function.

What do I have to do to allow `MyComponent` to use the default props *and* accept a function? I've tried adding another argument to the constructor of `MyComponent`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: [I get the desired result by declaring the `defaultProps` as a static property of the class](https://codesandbox.io/s/6wz23j1jl3).

Comment: Bob Horn just see the example of @thomas.winckell. It works as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

I tried and this is working :

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("props", props);
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  __TYPE: "MyDateRange"
};

render(
  <MyComponent onEnterKey={() => console.log("snuh")} />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

You can see it here : https://codesandbox.io/s/wkw0k0j5o8

Comment: So how is that different than what I'm doing?

Comment: __TYPE shows up, but the actual properties (like onChange, or ranges) don't.

Comment: I don't know what's different (expect maybe brackets positions) but both properties onEnterKey and __TYPE shows up on the example. Have you checked the link ?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `defaultProp` on the class outside of the constructor like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("props", props);
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <div> test </div>;
  }
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  __TYPE: "MyDateRange"
};
```

Alternatively, you can have `defaultProps` be a static property on the class:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    __TYPE: "MyDateRange"
  };
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("props", props);
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <div> test </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your first example is how it's current coded. For the second example, I'm getting a syntax error at the equals sign: `static defaultProps = ...`

Comment: @BobHorn Class properties are a [stage-2](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-2.html) proposal, so your development environment might not have it. The code in your question gives the impression that you set `MyComponent.defaultProps` *in the MyComponent constructor*. Is that not the case?

Comment: I'm sorry, that is *not* the case. The setting of default is after the component. I'll update the question.

Comment: Ok, so this is a mistake on my part. I thought our code was using the component directly. It's not. It's referencing an index file, which is then passing the props that we need. I'll delete this question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @BobHorn That's alright. I'm glad you found the issue.